# react-native-router-flux tab's on press is not working after select any tab

Tags: android, react-native, tabbar, react-native-router-flux

I recently updated my old **react native project** from **0.55.4 to 0.59.5**.Its working fine in iOS Release & Debug along with Android Debug. But in Android release mode, switching between tabs is not working properly.
I am using **react-native-router-flux** in that old project.

**Scenario:**

When the tab screen is opened by default first tab is selected which is fine, I select any other tab ,that particular tab gets selected. but when I click second time to select other tab then tabs onpress stops working. Earlier it was working fine in the **version 0.55.4**.

**Current version** of react native router flux **react-native-router-flux v4.0.6**

Please help :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you have any luck on solving this??

I got my issue after upgrade from RN 0.55.3 -> 0.59.10.

I have the same issue. My setup is a bit different, as I'm using

`"react-native-router-flux": "4.0.0-beta.31",`

`"react-native": "0.59.10",`

The tab click triggers `jumpToIndex(scene.index);`, and it actually works fine. Both, navigation actions and REACT_NATIVE_ROUTER_FLUX_BLUR && REACT_NATIVE_ROUTER_FLUX_FOCUS actions are called, and the scene is put to "focus". It works only for the first change, and then stops working. Though the debugger still goes the same path, and does everything identically as previously, when it works.

Also, setting `swipeEnabled: true,` allows me to navigate through the tabs without any issues, but if I swipe first, then the previously working first tab click doesn't work anymore..

I've tried different versions but that didn't help, also as router-flux upgrade makes a huge api change

MY SOLUTION:

I've actually solved my issue by upgrading react-navigation from `"1.0.0-beta.21` to `1.5.13`

Answer (score 0):

So, finally after huge struggle. I fixed this issue myself.

First of all, I deleted the node module folder (Please take backup before doing this step). Then, I installed node modules again via

npm install command

After that, I got some issues regarding androidx in some packages, I fixed those using

npm install --save-dev jetifier
npx jetify
npx react-native run-android (your app should correctly compile and work)

Also add

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

in your gradle.properties file

After these steps and removing the androidx related issues. I created release apk, installed it and everything was working fine.